# How to parse "in eo quod"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, augustinus

I am trying to translate this line by Augustine (found [here](https://www.augustinus.it/latino/genesi_lettera/index2.htm); in [liber tertius](https://www.augustinus.it/latino/genesi_lettera/genesi_lettera_03.htm) (24.37)), where it seems that the sense of the passage hinges in "in eo quod":

> Quia cum ea quae facta sunt, in eo quod facta sunt, quantum
> acceperunt, manent, sicut vel illa quae non peccaverunt, vel illa quae
> peccare non possunt; et singula bona, et in universo bona valde sunt.

When I take "in eo quod" as "by the fact that," I end up with a translation that doesn't make much sense:

> Because when these things which have been made, by the fact that they
> were made, as much as they have received, remain, just as either those
> things which have not sinned, or those which are not able to sin.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to parse "in eo quod"?

It appears that *in eo quod* is not a syntagma, but rather that the preposition *in* goes with *manent* to form a different syntagma.  The syntagma *maneō in quōd* is used to express to "adhere to something," "abide by something," and "remain in some condition."

Examples from [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=maneo&la=la#lexicon):

> 2. Pregn., to remain, last, endure, continue in any place or manner: “si in eo manerent, quod convenisset,” would adhere to, abide by that,
>    Caes. B. G. 1, 36, 5: “in vita,” to remain alive, Cic. Fam. 4, 13, 2:
>    “in veritate,” to adhere to the truth, id. Clu. 63, 176: “in
>    condicione,” to fulfil a condition, id. Att. 7, 15, 3: “in sententia,”
>    to adhere to, id. ib. 9, 2, 1: “in voluntate,” id. Fam. 5, 2, 10: “in
>    pristina mente,” id. Sest. 27, 58: “in officio,” Hirt. B. G. 8, 47:
>    “tu modo promissis maneas,” abide by, keep, Verg. A. 2, 160: “in
>    pactione,” to abide by, Nep. Ages. 2, 4: “an credi posse ullum populum
>    in ea condicione mansurum?” Liv. 8, 21, 6: “mansit in condicione atque
>    pacto,” Cic. Verr. 1, 6, 16:

With this knowledge, we can reduce the entire clause to the core statement: *...in eō...manent*.  In context, this can be understood as "they adhere to that" or "they remain so."

If we expand that core, we get: *in eō quod facta sunt...manent*.  The word *quod* can only be the predicative nominative governed by *facta sunt*, giving us: "they adhere to that which they were made" or "they remain as they were made."

If we expand further, we get: *in eō quod facta sunt, quantum accēpērunt, manent*, with an added parenthetical referring to the same thing as *eō* and *quod*.  I understand this as: "they adhere to what they were made, as much as they received" or "they remain as they were made, with respect to all they received."

I would translate the entire quote as:

> Because when those things that were made remain as they were made with
> respect to all they received, like either those things that did not
> sin or those that cannot sin, they are both individually good and very
> good in the totality.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the translation offered by the Works of Saint Augustine:

> Because when the things that have been made remain as what they were
> made, to the extent they received it, like those things that have not
> sinned or those that cannot sin, they are both good individually, and
> in the totality they are all very good.

The meaning is clear enough. The syntax is still slightly mysterious to me, as I want to word it "in eo (loco) in quo facta sunt."

Hopefully clarifying the intended meaning (and I don't see how anything else could be meant) will at least get us started down the path of explaining the construction.

Answer (score 5):

***quod** facta sunt,* in eō *manent* = **what** they [= entities] have been made (as/into), they remain *in that state/as that thing.* The singular is needed because *quae facta sunt* (as in the first clause) means ‘the entities that have been made’, so that the pronoun is no longer a subject complement (‘made as/into something’), but the subject itself.

Parallel to this is *quantum accēpērunt, manent,* which is supposed to be ***in eō** quantum accēpērunt manent* 'what amount of substance entities receive, they remain with that amount of substance,' i.e. the law of conservation of mass :-)

Comment: To clarify, is this a passive transformation of a double accusative construction? Cum manent ea in eo, quod Deus ea fecit.

Comment: @Kingshorsey Yep, we're thinking of the same thing: *quae Deus fēcit, **quod** ea fēcit, **in eō** manent.*